# When I try to "put" or "<%=" an ActiveRecord (rails) attribute, I get nil, but when I look at the object hash its actually there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, null, puts

So here is an example of a hash for a record of the 'properties' table, the attribute in question being 'owner'

```
Property.first #=>
  #<Property id: 3684, ss_property_id: 1, owner_full_name: "Holliday Associates", owner: "HA",
  owners_pctg: 100, tax_map_id: "0460001047", county: "Horry", description: "L.S. Alford", acreage:
  131.0, prop_taxes_2009: 180.72, prop_taxes_2010: 173.99, prop_taxes_2011: 172.94, notes: nil,
  created_at: "2013-04-03 01:16:23", updated_at: "2013-04-03 01:16:26">
```

When I do something like this, however

```
1.9.3p194 :011 > Property.first.owner
Property Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

it is nil.

EDIT: here is my model (dramatically over-simplified...)

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
end
```

Comment: Show us as much of your model as possible -- my guess is that you're overriding the `owner` method to display something else here.

Comment: Please show us your `Property` model.

Comment: You might also try `Property.find(3684).owner`.  Your second query doesn't impose any ORDER clause.  Databases are free to return records  however they want (some have a default order, but it's bad to rely on it).  It may well be that you second attempt isn't pulling back Property ID3684, but one whose owner is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My model ended up having a conflict with the :owner namespace. It actually belongs_to :owner, a new model I haven't even started using yet. The :owner namespace apparently got overwritten by the ActiveRelation method to the Owner model